# Can I use only mails of newly purchased domain?

Tags: web, dns, mail-server

I purchased domain from dodday and I have bluehost hosting server. I want to use that dodaddy domain mails only on my bluehost server.. is it possible?

Comment: If i'm correct you want to host your own email server? This is possible, are you using windows or linux?

Comment: yes.. actually i purchased domain from dodday and i already have bluehost server. i want to use that dodaddy domain mails only on my bluehost server

Answer (score 1):

Google for some email forwarding service. One of the first found was http://improvmx.com/, though I'm not vouch for its reliability.

In couple words,
- you need a service that will forward mails of your domain to some other email you already have. This can be email at @gmail.com
- your domain's dns mx records should point to the forwarding service

Comment: so we can't do without involving gmail?

Comment: If you don't host/own a server, you need some other server to keep your incoming mails. Yes, either your own server or some other email service as gmail should be involved.

Comment: i have my server on bluehost.. but domain is on dodday and i don't want to host that domain

Comment: You don't need to host it. Run some MTA(e.g. postfix) on your server at bluehost. And create MX records in DNS for your mail domain. MX records describes where the mail should be sent and should point to your server at bluehost. Server at bluehost must be able to handle(MTA) incoming mails.

Comment: [ImprovMX](https://improvmx.com) just pushed a new version of their website. I think the offer is more clear now, with a link to their ToS and Privacy Policy. You can manage your domains, forwarding emails and even add aliases now.